# Children components routing wont change to proper url

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am trying to set up router link for my settings page, whenever I click on Account, it directs me to `localhost/account` instead `localhost/settings/account` I've provided children for settings page, why is this happening?

Settings.vue

```
   router-link(to="/")
          button(class='hover:text-blue-500 focus:outline-none')
            | Profile
        router-link(:to="{name: 'Account'}")
          button(class='hover:text-blue-500 focus:outline-none')
            | Account
      router-view
```

```js
 {
        path: "/settings",
        name: "Settings",
        component: Settings,
        children: [{
            path: "",
            name: "Profile",
            component: Profile
          },
          {
            path: "/account",
            name: "Account",
            component: Account
          }
        ]
      },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the leading slash at account's path. Leading slash indicates it is a route from the root.

```
{
        path: "/settings",
        name: "Settings",
        component: Settings,
        children: [{
            path: "",
            name: "Profile",
            component: Profile
          },
          {
            path: "account", // now it works as intended
            name: "Account",
            component: Account
          }
        ]
      },
```

Comment: Thanks, do you might know why both of my items are being as `active` class whenever I switch menu item?

Comment: With both items you mean 'Profile' and 'Account'? You might need to use exact matching: https://router.vuejs.org/api/#exact